Disable New Outlook AutoInstallation
I am aware about Microsoft will to replace the old good mail application with new "new Outlook".
However i would like to stay behind and keep this old mail and callendar aplications active. Althought "new Outlook" is keeping auto installed.
Is there any way to stop this procedure and remain to the good old apps?
thank you in advance.
note: i have a windows 10 machine.

I think windows 10 will not be receiving any feature updates as it's end-of-life so you should be fine?

Setting UseNewOutlook To 0 here: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Preferences should accomplish what you want

As far as I know, New Outlook is gradually replacing the Mail that comes with the Windows system, maybe you can try to use it, although there will be some discomfort, but it will replace the inevitable trend of Mail. Of course, if you are still obsessed with Mail, I found a similar thread that many people find it useful, you can refer to https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-to-stop-the-new-outlook-from-automatically/34246983-2a13-4462-8a8a-df618c36ca3f
